# Нейронная сеть для анализа данных

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, нейронные-сети

Дело в том, что **очень срочно** нужна нейронная сеть для работы с данными. Объясняю ситуацию.

Есть веб-приложение, принцип его работы, пользователь вводит свои показатели здоровья (пульс, давление и т.д.). Данные храняться в базе данных.

Задача нейронной сети, брать данные с базы данных и сравнивать их с данными с датасетов и делать какие-то выводы, давать рекомендации. **Очень желательно на JavaScript.** Подойдёт любая, даже самая простая реализация.

Если кто-то может предоставить готовый вариант, буду безгранично благодарен. А так буду рад любой информации по этой теме. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Ну так это не работает, просто как чёрный ящик. Тем более для такой деликатной темы. Собственно, вам и нейросеть то может не нужна. Но вы должны разобраться со своими данными, понять их, это главное. В общем, это в сторону data science и машинного обучения. Если у вас данные не картинки и не тексты, то вам не нужно глубокое обучение и нейросети вообще. А интерфейс то можно на чём угодно сделать, тут основная работа будет в исследовании данных.

Comment: Я понимаю, что тут можно справиться и малой кровью, но дело как раз в том, чтобы в этом веб-приложении была какая-то интелектуальность, тобишь нейронная сеть, хотя бы елементарная, это объязателный пункт.

Comment: Да так то можно хоть Keras запускать, хоть что угодно https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js